# How to run Eclipse RCP application using command line

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am developing a small Eclipse RCP application and want to run it through command line arguments which takes three arguments as file paths.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are asking, if you mean accessing the command line arguments this is what to use:

In your `IApplication` you can get the command line arguments from the `IApplicationContext` argument using

```java
(String [])appContext.getArguments().get(IApplicationContext.APPLICATION_ARGS);
```

elsewhere in the application you can use

```java
Platform.getCommandLineArgs();
```